# How can I give PlaySound and alternate directory to search for my sound file?

Tags: c++, file, loops, wav, playsound

I've known about this website for a while now but this is my first post. Also, in terms of C++, I'm a complete noob (hence why I'm using PlaySound, I know there's many better ways to do it) so don't judge please :P

So I have this line of code:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("£100Play.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
```

As you can see £100Play is the sound file, all well and good. The file itself resides in the project folder. However, I'd like to make a folder with all the sounds inside as to not make the project folder all unorganized and messy. Is there anyway I can use PlaySound but tell it that it should search in the sound folder and not the project folder?

Thanks :)

Comment: Make the filename a full (absolute or relative) path.

Comment: Yup, that's it working now. Thanks very much Jongware!

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a file feel free to add a structure called OPENFILENAME ofnstr to your main function in project, and then call the omniscience GetSaveFileName(&ofnstr) ori GetOpenFileName(&ofnstr).

This will modify str.strFile that can replace the file quotes in your call. Be carefull to fill up the structure entirely or the call will fail and the file selection dialog will not show up.

Replace it with 
`OPENFILENAME ofnstr= { sizeof(OPENFILENAME), hWnd, NULL,
                         TEXT("All Files\0*.*\0Wave Files\0*.wav\0\0"), NULL,
                         0, 1, "", MAX_PATH, NULL, 0, "",
                         TEXT("Open Sound File"),
                         OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST|OFN_HIDEREADONLY, 0, 0,
                         TEXT(".wav"), 0, NULL, NULL }`